# send a function as prop to children

Tags: reactjs, select, parent-child, react-props

i have a class which has data in it and i am trying to send the data as options to a select element in the child.

Parent

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    value: [{key: '1', name: 'aaa'}, {key: '2', value: 'bbb'}],
  }
}
render(){
  const childProps = {
    getVal(){
    const val = this.state.value;
      return val.map((item) => {
        return (<option value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>);
      });
    }
  };

  return(
    //codes
    <Child {...childProps} />
  )
}
```

child

```
export const Child = ({ getVal }) => (
  <select>
    {getVal}
  </select>
);
Child.propTypes = {
  getVal: PropTypes.func,
};
```

But i am not getting any values on my select options. It says not found.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: getVal is a function, you need to call it, like this: `{getVal()}`, notice  =====> `()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You are not invoking the function .

```
export const Child = ({ getVal }) => (
  <select>
    {getVal()}
  </select>
);
Child.propTypes = {
  getVal: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Comment: can you share a sandbox example of what you are trying to acheive. Look the issues seems very simple, but not able to find out. a sandbox might help

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
 constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
        value: [{key: '1', name: 'aaa'}, {key: '2', value: 'bbb'}],
      }
      this.getVal = this.bind.getVal(this)
    }
    render(){
        getVal(){
          const val = this.state.value;
          return val.map((item) => {
            return (<option value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>);
          });
        }


      return(
        //codes
        <Child getVal ={this.getVal} />
      )
    }
```

Get the getVal function as props

```
    export const Child (
     <select>
        {this.props.getVal}
     </select>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to add the functions in the render method. As, whenever the render will be called the functions will get constructed again. So you can do this like:

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state={
    value: [{key: '1', name: 'aaa'}, {key: '2', value: 'bbb'}],
  }
}

getVal = () => this.state.value.map((item) => (
   <Option value={item.name} key={item.name}>{item.name}</Option>
));

render(){    
  return(
    <Child getVal={() => this.getVal} />
  )
}
```

child

```
export const Child = ({ getVal }) => (
  <select>
    {getVal()}
  </select>
);
Child.propTypes = {
  getVal: PropTypes.func,
};
```